# Combine strings (paths) without duplication of parts

Tags: python

I have two paths:

```
a = '/folder1/subfolder/'
b = '/subfolder/folder2'
```

How to combine them into

```
c = '/folder1/subfolder/folder2/'
```

in the simplest way?

Answer (score 1):

Checking only the last component of `a`, you could do:

```
A = a.strip('/').split('/')
B = b.strip('/').split('/')
if A[-1] == B[0]:
    print("/{}/".format("/".join(A + B[1:])))
```

Comment: Should use `os.path.sep` over `/`